# Is it possible to extract part of the session to be on top of the page when the screen is very narrowed

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Is it possible to extract part of the session to be on top of the page when the screen is very narrowed

See example below:

```
<div>
//Session A
    <Col className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center col-12" xl="8">
    <Preview
    />
    </Col>

//Session B
    <Col xl="4" sm="12" xs="12">
      <StudentProfile/>
      <Waring/>
    </Col>
</div>
```

When the screen is in large size, `<Preview>` occupy 8 column while `<StudentProfile/>` an `<Warning/>` takes 4 column as a whole in right side.

When the screen is getting narrowed, `<Preview>` takes up 12 column while  `<StudentProfile/>` an `<Warning/>` takes 12 column as a whole as well.

However, when screen is in narrow size,
I want the layout be like in this order

`<Warning/>` takes up all 12 column

`<Preview>` takes up all 12 column

`<StudentProfile/>` takes up all 12 column